# Forbidden error in apache virtual host setup

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, fuelphp

Hello I have been looking through internet articles forums to solve my issue and so far it has been to no avail. I am trying to set up an Apache virtual host for my FuelPHP development on localhost but I keep getting slammed with the error 403 message. Here is my current setup.

```
#/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/home/supercomputer/Desktop/PHP/fuelProject/public"
    ServerName   localhost.home
    <Directory "/home/supercomputer/Desktop/PHP/fuelProject/public" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have pointed my Docroot to the public folder inside my fuelProject. Also to make sure Apache had access to the server files, I set the permissions for all of the files recursively to read, write, and execute just to be a 100% safe. Any clues as to what else could be going wrong?

PS: I am running ubuntu raring (13.04)

PSS: And I am trying to visit localhost.home and localhost.home/index.php. I also get the following warnings upon restarting the server

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                                apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Fri May 03 15:46:58 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
 ... waiting apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
[Fri May 03 15:46:59 2013] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: Please Post your Apache Logs so that we could help properly , I some how guessed what might be the problem so you post back the issue by verifying it

Comment: Off topic. Try serverfault.com.

Comment: @user1000232 is your problem solved , If so please accept the answer you know the SO rules that you have to accept some answer . if not please post with your issue .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration I posted were working. The problem was with permissions. I had set only my containing fuel project folder to permission 777 but for some reason apache wanted access to almost all the folders containing it. Weird I know but setting all the permissions to 777, it worked. Reading the darn apache log sure helped. If you are having a similar problem, I suggest find the apache log and ACTUALLY READ IT

Comment: same here ... fresh uploaded files did not have read permission ... after setting 777 everything worked

Comment: I hope people will not do this on their production environment.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the correct way of adding Vhost for fuelphp application or any other php application

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost.home
    DocumentRoot /home/supercomputer/Desktop/PHP/fuelProject/public
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    <Directory /home/supercomputer/Desktop/PHP/fuelProject/public>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And also the below line is not required I dont know why you have added

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

After doing all above add a host entry to your machine to do that

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

add an entry of the virtual host

```
127.0.0.1  localhost.home
```

After doing all these things

restart Apache by running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And just load http://localhost.home in your browser you should be able to see your site up and running .

If you still get forbidden error .you need to give permissions to your whole application folder

follow run these commands to do so

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/supercomputer/Desktop/PHP

sudo chmod -R 775 /home/supercomputer/Desktop/PHP
```

At last add yourself to www-data group

```
sudo adduser yourUserName www-data
```

Comment: After changing my DocumentRoot from the default `/var/www` to something custom and adding an appropriate Directory rule in my Apache configuration file, I was getting a forbidden error on localhost. Adding the entry you suggested to `/etc/hosts` and restarting Apache fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Testeed on Ubuntu 14.04: I did everything above but I didn't work. I missed to allow access to the directory in my **apache2.conf**. This is needed if you don't use a standard directory like /var/www or /usr/share/.

```
<Directory /usr/local/vufind>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This was mentioned on the4 default PHP site. It's worth reading it!